# Is this a metric on matrices?

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces

In the set of $n$-by-$n$ reversible real matrices, decide whether 
$$d(A,B)=\ln (\lVert A^{-1}B\rVert\cdot\lVert B^{-1}A\rVert)$$
defines a metric and/or semi-metric.
Can you please help me to solve it?

Comment: what did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Im clueless, specifically about how to identify metric characteristics for ln and for reverse funtion on A and B... generally clueless...

Comment: do you use given norm on the set of reversible matrices?

Comment: I think here the norm ||.|| is defined as an Euclidian norm on Rn vector space.

Comment: So it's a norm on $\Bbb R^{n^2}$..?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Definition

Comment: @pxc3110 That doesn't look right to me, since those B's should be A's,  so you'd have the norm of the identity twice, which would be 1, so you would have d(A,A)=0

Comment: Correction:I don't think it defines a metric, since: $d(A,A)=ln(|A^{−1}A||A^{−1}A|)≥ln|I_n|$, at least not if $|I|>1$

Comment: So, by having ||l||<1 i can show it is not a metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if it is a metric, first you should define what $||A||$ means; it is of course a matrix norm, but which one?

Unfortunately not all norms work; for example, to satisfy the property $d(A, B ) = 0 \iff A = B$ we need $||I|| = 1$ but this is not true for all the matrix norms.

Anyhow you're book seems to assume that your matrix already satisfy the first axioms (that is, $d(A, B) \ge 0$,  $d(A, B) = d(B, A)$ (this is obvious) and $d(A, B) = 0 \iff A = B$)

Now, you just have to check wether the triangle inequality holds;

Is $$d(A, B) \le d(A, C) + d(C, B)$$ for every invertible matrix $A, B, C$ ?

Things are greatly simplified if we have a [sub multiplicative norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).
Assuming it is, we want to show that 
$$\ln(||A^{-1}B|| \cdot ||B^{-1}A||) \le \ln(||A^{-1}C|| \cdot ||C^{-1}A||) + \ln(||C^{-1}B|| \cdot ||B^{-1}C||)$$
Taking the exponential on both sides

$$||A^{-1}B|| \cdot ||B^{-1}A|| \le ||A^{-1}C|| \cdot ||C^{-1}A|| \cdot ||C^{-1}B|| \cdot ||B^{-1}C||$$

Now, if the norm is multiplicative, write $B = CC^{-1}B$ and get $$||A^{-1}B|| = ||A^{-1}CC^{-1}B|| \le ||A^{-1}C||\cdot ||C^{-1}B||$$
Now the same trick, with $A = CC^{-1}A$
$$||B^{-1}A|| = ||B^{-1}CC^{-1}A|| \le ||B^{-1}C|| \cdot ||C^{-1}A||$$
and substituting you get indeed $1 \le 1$ which is true.

To recap:

1) It is not a distance for every norm. You should at least have, for example $||I|| = 1$

2) Anyhow your book seems to assume that the first axioms are respected, so you just need to check wether it respect the triangle inequality or not. For a general norm I have not been able to find an answer, but for a sub multiplicative norm then you get that $d(A, B)$ is indeed a metric because it respect the triangle inequality (as shown above)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didnt know about sub multiplicative norms, now I wil read and learn more about it :)

Comment: @Behnoosh You're welcome. Not though that if the norm is not sub-multiplicative this does not answer your question :)